# Doing integration testing on Oracle ADF application

Tags: java, oracle, integration-testing, oracle-adf, cactus

I have an ADF application which running on my server. I was trying to run some integration test cases on it. I used to use apache cactus framework to run testing on normal web applications. My test cases would extend CactusStrutsTestCase and will be run.
I tried to approach, ADF application with same concept. But I am getting connection refused error

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
```

So my question is that , is it possible to do testing in ADF application with a ServletTestcase which is part of Cactus framework ?

Thanks
Jijoy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is possible.  I know, because I've done it.

First off, ditch genuine Apache Cactus.  It's not being supported anymore.  You want to download [JSFUnit](http://www.jboss.org/jsfunit) and use that instead.  It makes use of Apache Cactus but is still being actively maintained.

I suggest you create your own test case which extends ServletTestCase instead of using ServletTestCase directly.

```
public class EJBTestCase extends ServletTestCase {
protected InitialContext context;

public static final String userId = "demouser";


public EJBTestCase(String string) {
    super(string);
}

private InitialContext getInitialContext() throws NamingException {
  Hashtable env = new Hashtable();

  env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "username");
  env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");


     return new InitialContext(env);
}

public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();

    context = getInitialContext();

}

public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    super.tearDown();

    context.close();
}

public EJBTestCase() {
    super();
}
}
```

Next, you need to setup your web.xml file:

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>JSFUnitFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jboss.jsfunit.framework.JSFUnitFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
...

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>JSFUnitFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>ServletTestRunner</servlet-name>
      </filter-mapping>
      <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>JSFUnitFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>ServletRedirector</servlet-name>
      </filter-mapping>

...

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletRedirector</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.jsfunit.framework.JSFUnitServletRedirector</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletTestRunner</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cactus.server.runner.ServletTestRunner</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

...

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletRedirector</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ServletRedirector</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletTestRunner</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ServletTestRunner</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Finally, when you run your test cases you must pass in the cactus.contextURL parameter.

```
-Dcactus.contextURL=http://127.0.0.1:7101/MyApp
```

I assume you are using JDeveloper.  You can then set this under Project Properties > Run/Debug/Profile -> Edit > Launch Settings -> Java Options.